# CSS3 Transition - Fade out effect

Tags: css, css-transitions

I am trying to implement the "fade out" effect in pure CSS. Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dYBD2/). I did look into a couple of solutions online, however, after reading the [documentation online](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_animations.asp), I am trying to figure out why the slide animation would not work. Any pointers?

```css
.dummy-wrap {
  animation: slideup 2s;
  -moz-animation: slideup 2s;
  -webkit-animation: slideup 2s;
  -o-animation: slideup 2s;
}

.success-wrap {
  width: 75px;
  min-height: 20px;
  clear: both;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.successfully-saved {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 15px 40px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #00b953;
}

@keyframes slideup {
  0% {top: 0px;}
  75% {top: 0px;}
  100% {top: -20px;}
}

@-moz-keyframes slideup {
  0% {top: 0px;}
  75% {top: 0px;}
  100% {top: -20px;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes slideup {
  0% {top: 0px;}
  75% {top: 0px;}
  100% {top: -20px;}
}

@-o-keyframes slideup {
  0% {top: 0px;}
  75% {top: 0px;}
  100% {top: -20px;}
}
```

```html
<div class="dummy-wrap">
  <div class="success-wrap successfully-saved">Saved</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 130, accepted):

You can use transitions instead:

```
.successfully-saved.hide-opacity{
    opacity: 0;
}

.successfully-saved {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: center;

    transition: opacity 3s ease-in-out;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: dont need browser prefixes these days just plain ol' ... transition: opacity 3s ease-in-out;

Answer (score 260):

Here is another way to do the same.

**fadeIn effect**

```
.visible {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 2s linear;
}
```

**fadeOut effect**

```
.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: visibility 0s 2s, opacity 2s linear;
}
```

`UPDATE 1:`
I found more up-to-date tutorial [CSS3 Transition: fadeIn and fadeOut like effects to hide show elements](https://www.aspneto.com/fade-in-and-fade-out-effect-using-css3-transition.html) and [Tooltip Example: Show Hide Hint or Help Text using CSS3 Transition](https://www.aspneto.com/tooltip-example-show-hide-hint-help-text-using-css3-transition.html) here with sample code.

`UPDATE 2:` (Added details requested by @big-money)

When showing the element (by switching to the visible class), we want the `visibility:visible` to kick in instantly, so it’s ok to transition only the opacity property. And when hiding the element (by switching to the hidden class), we want to delay the `visibility:hidden` declaration, so that we can see the fade-out transition first. We’re doing this by declaring a transition on the visibility property, with a 0s duration and a delay. You can see a detailed article [here](https://fvsch.com/code/transition-fade/test5.html).

I know I am too late to answer but posting this answer to save others time.

Comment: Nice answer, I'm looking to add `display:none` to erase the box when the "hide" animation ends, any idea ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you need here but you can try `display:block` instead of `visibility: visible` in `.visible` class likewise `display:none` instead of `visibility: hidden` in `.hidden` class from above example.

Comment: @MMTac That doesn't work since `display` isn't one of the [animatable CSS properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties). See [Animating from “display: block” to “display: none”](http://www.impressivewebs.com/animate-display-block-none/).

Answer (score 19):

Since `display` is not one of the animatable CSS properties.
One `display:none` fadeOut animation replacement with pure CSS3 animations, just set `width:0` and `height:0` at last frame, and use `animation-fill-mode: forwards` to keep `width:0` and `height:0` properties.

```
@-webkit-keyframes fadeOut {
    0% { opacity: 1;}
    99% { opacity: 0.01;width: 100%; height: 100%;}
    100% { opacity: 0;width: 0; height: 0;}
}  
@keyframes fadeOut {
    0% { opacity: 1;}
    99% { opacity: 0.01;width: 100%; height: 100%;}
    100% { opacity: 0;width: 0; height: 0;}
}

.display-none.on{
    display: block;
    -webkit-animation: fadeOut 1s;
    animation: fadeOut 1s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

Comment: Look into [**High Performance Animations**](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/high-performance-animations/). You should avoid using CSS properties that triggers re-layout, `width` and `height` are both sensitive.

Answer (score 8):

This is the working code for your question.
Enjoy Coding....

```html
 <html>
       <head>
       
          <style>
             
             .animated {
                background-color: green;
                background-position: left top;
                padding-top:95px;
                margin-bottom:60px;
                -webkit-animation-duration: 10s;animation-duration: 10s;
                -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;animation-fill-mode: both;
             }
             
             @-webkit-keyframes fadeOut {
                0% {opacity: 1;}
                100% {opacity: 0;}
             }
             
             @keyframes fadeOut {
                0% {opacity: 1;}
                100% {opacity: 0;}
             }
             
             .fadeOut {
                -webkit-animation-name: fadeOut;
                animation-name: fadeOut;
             }
          </style>
          
       </head>
       <body>
       
          <div id="animated-example" class="animated fadeOut"></div>
          
       </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Please attach an explanation of your solution: how it works? why it's different from the other solutions already posted?

Comment: @lifeisfoo I tried with above all solutions, but this is the simple and easiest way to do it and one more important thing is the text will fade away automatically after some seconds(10). So no need of any click.

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to add a position property to the `.dummy-wrap` class, and the top/left/bottom/right values don't apply to statically positioned elements (the default)

http://jsfiddle.net/dYBD2/2/

Comment: Thanks, but how would i hide after the transition altogether?

Comment: There are several ways - you can just increase the `top` value so that it moves "off" the viewport or you can use opacity for the animation so that it fades out like you seem to want ..

Comment: great.. I got that, but one more question, Why does the hidden div come back the fade out?

Answer (score 3):

```
.fadeOut{
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.83);
    border-radius: 8px;
    box-shadow: silver 3px 3px 5px 0px;
    border: 2px dashed yellow;
    padding: 3px;
}
.fadeOut.end{
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.0);
    box-shadow: none;
    border: 0px dashed yellow;
    border-radius: 0px;
}
```

[demo here.](http://jsbin.com/cosige/2/edit)

Answer (score 1):

You can remove element from the page via Position Absolute;

then:

```
transform: translateX(-200vw);
opacity: 0;
transition: opacity 0.2s;
transition-delay: 200ms;
```

then when you want element to appear, use this class:

```
opacity: 1;
transform: translateX(0px);
```

logic here is that:  Transform -> removes/places element into the view INSTANTLY; while opacity takes care of the Fade In / Out effects

We also added slight delay with transiton-delay, to make it little bit better

NOTE: if you don't like TranslateX, you can replace it with scale(0); scale(1)  -> to make element appear and disappear instantly

Answer (score 0):

This may help :-

```css
.cardiv{
    height:200px;
    width:100px;
    background-color:red;
    position:relative;
    text-align:center;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.moreinfo{
    height:0%;
    transition: height 0.5s;
    opacity:1;
    position: absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    background-color:blue;
}

.cardiv:hover .moreinfo{

    opacity: 1;
    height:100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<div class="cardiv">
    <div class="moreinfo">Hello I am inside div</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `forwards` fill-mode in CSS for it to remain on the last part of the animation.

I suggest using `transform: tranlsateY(-20px);` instead of using css positions, but if you insist of using it then set the `.dummy-wrap` position into `absolute`

```css
.dummy-wrap {
  animation: slideup 2s forwards;
  -moz-animation: slideup 2s forwards;
  -webkit-animation: slideup 2s forwards;
  -o-animation: slideup 2s forwards;
  position: absolute;
}

@keyframes slideup {
    0% {
        top: 0px;
    }
    75% {
        top: 0px;
    }
    100% {
        top: -20px;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="dummy-wrap">
  <div class="success-wrap successfully-saved">Saved (Slide UP)</div>
</div>
```