# Loader javascript sessionStorage don't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, loader, session-storage

I have this script and it works in half; The loader displaying in all pages but I want to show it only in home for first access.

```
sessionStorage.setItem('visited' , false);        
var visited = sessionStorage.getItem('visited');
if (visited != true) {
    jQuery(window).load(function() {
        jQuery(".famous-loader-overlay").delay(1500).fadeOut(1500);
    });
} else {
    jQuery(window).load(function() {
        jQuery(".famous-loader-overlay").hide();
    });
}
sessionStorage.setItem('visited', true);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Session storage keep data in string so you get always false. Try:

```
visited != "true"
```

Comment: thanks! It work but after the first show in the other pages it is shown for a moment before disappearing, how I can fix it? Thanks

Comment: Set time 1ms before load and use remove instead of hide.

Comment: how I set time? because I used the remove but it can be seen anyway

Comment: see example for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34478502/set-time-on-a-message-using-javascript-jquery  time under your hand

Answer (score 0):

hide it in case it's just visited and set visited only if it was not

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {
    if (sessionStorage.getItem('visited')) {
        jQuery(".famous-loader-overlay").hide();
        return;
    }
    jQuery(".famous-loader-overlay").delay(1500).fadeOut(1500);
    sessionStorage.setItem('visited', "1");
});
```

Comment: thanks! It work but after the first show in the other pages it is shown for a moment before disappearing, how I can fix it? Thanks