# Make HTML element disappear with CSS animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, css-animations

I want to know if there is a way to make an HTML element disappear with an animation of CSS. So when the element gets removed from the page by some script, an animation shall display before the element actually gets removed.

Is this possible in an easy way? Or do I need to set a timer to my script that starts the animation with a duration of X and removes the element after time X?

Comment: this could help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15907079/css3-transition-fade-out-effect

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: This will entirely depend on what effect you are going for and how the removal of the element is supposed to affect other elements after removal.

Comment: I added an answer that works perfectly, it disappears with fade and display property is set to none

Comment: @Froxx I figured out that I had a mistake, see again if this does what you want

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the script is actually removing the DOM element, I don't believe there's a way to fade it out.  I think the timer is your only option.

Comment: It looks like you're right. Well, the way with the timeout isn't that bad anyway. I just wondered if there's an easier way without JS.

Answer (score 25):

I would get fancy with keyframes

```
@keyframes myAnimation{
  0%{
    opacity: 1;
    transform: rotateX(90deg);
  }
  50%{
    opacity: 0.5;
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
  }
  100%{
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
    transform: rotateX(90deg);
  }
}

#myelement{
    animation-name: myAnimation;
    animation-duration: 2000ms;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

Comment: Display: none at the end of the animation doesn't work (these days?!), I am trying this now in Chrome without "luck".

Comment: See related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46575220/css-animation-fill-mode-not-working-for-displaynone

Answer (score 6):

I use jQuery to implement this.

```js
//jQuery
$(document).ready(function() {
  var target = $("#div");
  $("#btn").click(function() {
    removeElement(target);
  });
});

function removeElement(target) {
  target.animate({
    opacity: "-=1"
  }, 1000, function() {
    target.remove();
  });
}
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="div"></div>
  <input type="button" value="fadeout" id="btn">
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

Use transitions like this:

```js
function waithide()
{
  var obj = document.getElementById("thisone");
  obj.style.opacity = '0';
  window.setTimeout(
    function removethis()
    {
      obj.style.display='none';
    }, 300);
}
```

```css
div
{
  height:100px;
  width :100px;
  background:red;
  display:block;
  opacity:1;
  transition : all .3s;
  -wekit-transition : all .3s;
  -moz-transition : all .3s;
}
```

```html
<div id="thisone" onclick="waithide()"></div>
```

Comment: Well, the animation works indeed, but that's not what I asked for. I asked whether it's possible to play a CSS animation when I remove an element - not how to hide an element (that's still there in the end).

Comment: I know that it works... ^^ But the element is still in the DOM at the end. That's my problem. I want to remove the element from the DOM (not simply hide it with `display: none`), and I wanted to know if there's a solution without JS's `setTimeout()`. But I think I will just go the timeout way.

Comment: I didn't get what you want, do you want to remove the source code of the object like users won't see it in inspect the element? or just it doesn't affect  in anyway the code?

Comment: I have a script that displays every single record in a data table as an element. This table gets modified during runtime, so the DOM (the HTML source code) gets modified during runtime, too. When I add a new element for a new record of the data table, it's no problem because the normal `animation` property of CSS gets triggered. But when the element gets removed it's a bit harder, because it seems that there's no integrated listener for that. And my question is if there is one I don't know about. But it doesn't seem to be like this so I need to set a timeout that delays the element's deletion.

Comment: Oh ok I get it now

Answer (score 3):

I think you would have to do it in two steps. first the animate. Then, after animate is done, remove the elem. See the function below. Perhaps it could be put in a jquery plugin?

```
<style>
    #test{
        background: red;
        height: 100px;
        width: 400px;
        transition: height 1s;   
    }

    #test.hide {
        height: 0;       
    }

</style>

<div id="test"> </div>

<button>Hide the Div</button>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.js"></script>
<script>


        $('button').click(function(){
            removeWithAnimate('#test');
        });


        function removeWithAnimate(id){
            $(id).addClass('hide');
            setTimeout( function(){
                    $(id).remove()
            },1000);;   
        }

</script>
```

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  removeWithAnimate('#test');
});

function removeWithAnimate(id) {
  $(id).addClass('hide');
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(id).remove()
  }, 1000);;
}
```

```css
#test {
  background: red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 400px;
  transition: height 1s;
}

#test.hide {
  height: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="test"> </div>

<button>Hide the Div</button>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.js"></script>
```

Comment: That would be a nice solution, if the element could stay in the DOM, but it doesn't. I need to remove it, but thanks.

Comment: @Froxx: "if the element could stay in the DOM, but it doesn't" true..."I need to remove it" yes this is what happens after 1 second (when the animation on height is finished). This will do what you prefer, but it involves a timer being set. The solution by Buffalo is without a (javascript at least) timer but does not finally remove the element, it resides in the DOM but isn't displayed anymore.

Answer (score -1):

```
transition: .5s;
```

invisible:

```
opacity: 0;
```

visible:

```
opacity: 1;
```

transition will make it appear and disappear smoothly.