# CSS animation-fill-mode not working for display:none

Tags: css, css-animations

I have the following code to show/hide buttons on a carousel based on css classes. Everything works as intended, except on hideButton, the display is not set to "none" after the animation is done.

The effect is that although the button fades, it's still on top of underlying items and prevents clicks from hitting them.

```
.pills-tab-carousel__button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 100%;
  width: 64px;
  animation: showButton .5s forwards;
}

.pills-tab-carousel__button--hidden {
  animation: hideButton .5s forwards;
}

@keyframes hideButton {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    display: block;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    display: none;
  }
}

@keyframes showButton {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    display: none;
  }
  1% {
    opacity: 0.01;
    display: block;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not to use `visibility: hidden;` since your element is already position absolute so you don't need to worry about layout.

Check out the fiddle I just created:

https://jsfiddle.net/uvxeqaLn/

Comment: I didn't realize that `visibility: hidden` allowed elements to be clicked through! I thought it took up space and also captured pointer events. Thanks!

Comment: Many reasons, perhaps you don't want it to take up space, be red out by screen-readers, take keyboard focus, etc. etc.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot animate the `display` property.

As an alternative you can set the property `pointer-events: none;` which will allow clicks to pass through the hidden element.

Just be aware that this is not supported in any IE versions prior to IE11.