# How to make a div disappear

Tags: html, css

How can I make a div disappear in 5s when hovering by only using css? I tried something like this:

```
.a {
  display: block;
  transition: display 5s;
}
.a:hover {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: This link will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39513705/make-html-element-disappear-with-css-animation

Answer (score 0):

Display property doesn't get affected by transitions. You can use opacity instead.

```
a{
    opacity:1;
    transition: opacity 5s linear;
}

a:hover{
    opacity:0;
    transition: opacity 5s linear;
}
```

Here is a working demo.

```css
a{
    opacity:1;
    transition: opacity 5s linear;
}

a:hover{
    opacity:0;
    transition: opacity 5s linear;
}
```

```html
<a> I will disapear </a>
```

Answer (score -1):

yes but its can not be done right away like you have been doing. It requires a little more effort.

```
<a class="hide" href="#">Make me disappear in 5s </a>
```

CSS:

```
a.hide:hover {
    animation: animateVisibility 0s ease-in 5s forwards;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes animateVisibility {
   to {
       width:0;
       height:0;
       visibility:hidden;
        }
 }
```