# how to give fadeout effect to a page in javascript without using jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, fadeout

.. i tried using the code in which the loading will keep on increasing till 100 until a new page will open..

```
if(loading==90){
  preload.style.animation = "fadeOut 2s ease";
}
```

but its not working

Comment: provide some more code you did

Comment: you want a `transition` - `animation` is far more complicated than you think - and transitions (and animations) don't understand "fadeOut", just because it's what you want it to do - read [some documentation about transition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/transition)

Comment: You should do a css transition. There's a link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15907079/css3-transition-fade-out-effect

Comment: @Banzay  if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener('load', cool, false);
}   
function cool() {
    var preload =document.getElementById("preload");
    var loading = 0;
    var id = setInterval(frame,64);
    
    function frame(){
        if(loading==100){
            clearInterval(id);
            window.open("test1.html","_self");
        }
        else{
            loading = loading + 1;
            if(loading==90){
                preload.style.opacity = 0.5;
            }
        }
    }
};

Answer (score 0):

Use css opacity, 1 is full visible, 0 is hidden and 0.5 is half visible.

```
document.getElementById("yourId").style.opacity = "0.5";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can append class to `preload` element

```js
if (window.addEventListener) {
 window.addEventListener('load', cool, false); 
}
function cool() {

 var preload = document.getElementById("preload");
 var loading = 0;
 var id = setInterval(frame,64);

 function frame() {

 if(loading == 100) {
  clearInterval(id);
//  window.open("test1.html","_self"); 
 }

 if(++loading == 90){ 
         preload.className = "ld"; 
 } 
 }
};
```

```css
#preload {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: tomato;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  transition: all 2s ease;
}
.ld {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="preload"></div>
test string
```