# Creating a fading image in JavaScript by changing opacity over a period of time

Tags: javascript, html, css, opacity, fading

I am new to JavaScript. I am really intrigued to figure out an easy technique for changing the opacity of an image that is laying on top of another image to reveal that bottom image gradually. I want to do this by fading out. In other words subtracting from the style.opacity property gradually after each second passes with time.

I came up with the following but it doesn't seem to work for me.

The current state of my code changes the opacity suddenly goes from 1 to the negatives (-0.1, -0.2, -0.3, etc). Which basically does a transition from the top image immediately to revealing the bottom one.

I want to gradually go from opacity of 1 to (0.9, 0.8, 0.7, etc) as each second passes.

I want to accomplish this in pure JavaScript. I found something similar in CSS but I don't want to use that approach.

I assume that `(var currentOp = document.getElementById('guitar2').style.opacity;)` treats the currentOp variable as a string. Because of this I tried a combination of parsing to float, making the subtraction and changing back to string, setting the opacity gradually over time to not avail.

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    #guitar1
    {
        position: relative;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }

    #guitar2
    {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        opacity: 1;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body onload="runTime()">
    <script>

        var timer;

        function reduceOpacity()
        {
            var op = document.getElementById('guitar2');
            var currentOp = document.getElementById('guitar2').style.opacity;
            //currentOp = (parseFloat(currentOp) -  0.1).toString();
            currentOp -= 0.1;
            op.style.opacity = currentOp;
        }

        function runTime() 
        {
            timer = setInterval(reduceOpacity, 1000);
        }

    </script>
    <h4 id="header">Gibson Les Paul</h4>
    <div style="position: relative; left: 0; top: 0;">
        <img src="gibson1.png" id="guitar1" width="500" />
        <img src="gibson2.png" id="guitar2" width="500" />
    </div>
    <button type="button" onclick='document.getElementById("header").innerHTML = "yea"'>Click Me!</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You could always use pure CSS: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11681331/3684265

Comment: You should check out the link posted by @imvain2. Here is another similar approach that I think is even easier to follow: [CSS3 Transition - Fade out effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15907079/css3-transition-fade-out-effect#20910008)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `getComputedStyle` and `getPropertyValue` to retrieve an accurate representation of the element's styling on load.

`style.property` has a habit of not being up to date, will sometimes pull default values inexplicably, and many values aren't able to be grabbed until they are set. If you `console.log(op.style.opacity)` in your original example you'll see that it pulls an empty string and then counts down from there after transposing it to 0.

You then use `clearInterval` to stop the function from continuously running after that point.

```
    //get the style value with getComputedStyle, which is an accurate representation of 
    //all element styling on load.
    var currentOp = getComputedStyle(op).getPropertyValue("opacity");
    // clear the interval if opacity is less than or equal to 0
    if(currentOp <= 0) clearInterval(timer);

    console.log(currentOp);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    #guitar1
    {
        position: relative;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }

    #guitar2
    {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        opacity: 1;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body onload="runTime()">
    <script>

        var timer;

        function reduceOpacity()
        {
            var op = document.getElementById('guitar2');
            
            //get the style value with getComputedStyle, which is an accurate representation of 
            //all element styling on load.
            var currentOp = getComputedStyle(op).getPropertyValue("opacity");
            // clear the interval if opacity is less than or equal to 0
            if(currentOp <= 0) clearInterval(timer);
            
            console.log(currentOp);
            //currentOp = (parseFloat(currentOp) -  0.1).toString();
            currentOp -= 0.1;
            op.style.opacity = currentOp;
        }

        function runTime() 
        {
            timer = setInterval(reduceOpacity, 1000);
        }

    </script>
    <h4 id="header">Gibson Les Paul</h4>
    <div style="position: relative; left: 0; top: 0;">
        <img src="gibson1.png" id="guitar1" width="500" />
        <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAOEAAADhCAMAAAAJbSJIAAAAP1BMVEWzs7P///+xsbG2traurq7y8vLLy8u+vr7Hx8fX19fExMTh4eHAwMDc3Nzn5+f8/Pzq6ur29vbT09Pv7++oqKiXjvXjAAAHrUlEQVR4nO2d6ZaDIAyFFVBbtVrrvP+zDgTcderGkpzJn6kL5H4QILbqRFHEMxbRNJZx+FvHnCYi43Ut//A6jmuSiEyjRVkc00QEwDjOzAd6iCMumogTKoqIMyZ6iAsiaogrPLQQV2koIW6w0EHcJKGC+AcHDcQ/KSggfmHAj/iVADviDv24EXepx4y4UztexN3KsSIe0I0T8ZBqjIgHNeNDPKwYG+IJvbgQT6nFhHhSKx7E00qxIF7QiQPxkkoMiBc1ho94WWHoiDfoCxvxFnUhI96kLVzE25SFinijrjARb1UVIuLNmsJDvF1RaIgW9ISFaEVNSIiWtISDaE1JKIgWdYSBaFVFCIiWNfhHtK7AN6ID/34RnXj3iejItz9EZ559ITr06wfRqVcfiI59ukd07tG1Qw9R49all5Hv0qmn2dudW28rsCvHHrMoN669ZsIunHu+mrHv3vflmnUB3gFtSwgA0K6IIABtyggE0J6QYABtSQkI0I6YoABtyAkM8H5BwQHeLSlAwHtFBQl4p6xAAe8TFizgXdICBrxHXNCAd8gLHPC6wOABr0pEAHhNJArAKzKRAJ4XigbwrFREgOfEogI8IxcZ4HHB6ACPSkYIeEw0SsAjspEC7heOFnCvdMSA+8SjBtwjHzngdwD0gB1CnG0cpvDeTcY/0tJ1Bpaqg7gBpTFlJ47927/tNDaJo0VILWOMCWXjEkMV/dmTYmxSYHKQLaJ4Xt/lIOepspwbBfLzZFbM5I7J+UykRZu0RcoEbOdpZ1xvLOoR0adqk/crEyOXfOz9UUZ9A5R9fdlC3DmD2VxN6KkSwOSn56g6kcgdn/GOZ9zZSxUQ7347Z6KSf4BjVA8ruhNaPaWyx7C4lN2x5qn52auvT7rtDmtxFwmlIqGVjYG4OpD01TPexIM1siMAqicsFoQsq0clcjYjHLybNXOdcCrqNGHMF4RC++vjVi/uTVVUtSnxjRCaKE6qqoUPJdskBP+bhPFpQPDxYPypJc0JNcjL7IGYrXOYaVJ56M2AsO/jJaFQfZ5wVYBDPK8QliIqIfZboQnrPmZKaDgQd74TNSGIL8SMELTUvUuWqg40o56JpBLRF0Io0ZrD0N2yseaEKnQFa/SnNcLopxla+SwhU5UsCNU0Upe6CdRma0LJ8DMjO/mBXtWE9Y+a34UmhC4cqmugAdYIdTjLJgPCn2490oTsp75K+MnTt0abRancKlT1b2hVoUVMTBHWb2Vtpvvw+ZJmgl5V8BrmKdWj+QahmYdhHOr6HnocGnEbee9OQmNsNtMwpTOD2aY/de5oOdP09mQs7wH6FvuwdUL2gQDZnGnOLxcDYT4nVFElxxg3/dGNigOEaTy5rNKxu0Goz90iLK+vFpVejsaEqv5UMDX8GhH1k9KCsK6UvU2UNmCXCKG+Kh8SgiK6kNRA6KnMEbbGhNA9KmtSTku1J54mPN1Js5kGNvSps7jWmxuETxgMo5nGtLGK3teFlGbWMWNCNg45WBnqcX4T9RPE9mqhQNu+BBzmWzNNC8vEcrXI3vGV9f4PQhj6gzGTb3x6nFT975ovhCoMHuYwU66SjdVC5PGwWkzXQ3VOcTEvnREKuGCBBGYwxQ0p2AeWfKZScL4SpdOcBkqkqgQTMOIf3YqvneicRtoj1kNhGaU5NBPf0n+G8K0WtBxa/Cng+sxMqqZbE3ldk30gBdd5aV3AzJCtZW06HUs5z4su2IGwUE44OHkX1bvuD6o4KcYzjcza4m5FvokQ7Dksg/1aZTppsC4Ota1m3tMSMCaBEKxk48wbgn25Wphqt77Lu0A4aTjVsCB4PDhz8f3qaVJCj6YxYbk4uEII7tvTnZg1SZP3W6xJwJo0V/v7tb9IEu2C8Ze+3mieTF/PmRJJU8oZX24IU0/TzVi80CWq0ojMOycZy+Bj+64+3CxXz74+ucwocaXe2ZzvRCHEdMukvZOvVsRwFpMXO3nWf+3AuhLCbPQFhoxbcFli5GZUYvAXzetjg7ih3n/7t39bt25MnTmKwRhv6rputpIOcxTxTxfmx7XtrAr774fkfwMm/zs++XsxyN9PQ/6eKPL3tZG/N5H8/aXk7xEmf583+Xv1yT9vQf6ZGfLPPZF/do3884fknyEl/xww+We5yT+PT/6dCuTfi0H+3Sbk309D/h1D5N8TRf5dX+Tf10b+nXvk35tI/t2XtiV4R7QvwDOiC/deEd0494joyrU3RHeOPSG6dOsF0a1TD4iuXTpHdN+mjj36GBdOffqZ2xx69bU+OfPrL8dw5NlnnujEt99c34F339dr1v37BhxuybWkwD+gZQ0hAFpVEQagxUANBdCaknAALWkJCdBKoIYFaEFPaIC3KwoP8OZADRHwVlVhAt6oK1TA2wI1XMCbtIUMeIu6sAFvCNTQAS8rDB/wokYMgJcCFQfgBZ1YAE8rxQN4MlAxAZ5SiwvwhF5sgIcDFR/gQc0YAQ+pxgl4IFCxAu5Wjhdwp3bMgLsCFTfgDv3YAb8S4Af8EqgUAP+koAH4BwcVwM1ApQO4wUIJcJWGFuBKoFIDXBDRA5wxUQScBCpNwDEXhf99tmqmFzN4/SRFQINYqxdv1tbu9fNsErGGDzyjCSgRM9mDv1k6auXmcfibAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC" id="guitar2" width="500" />
    </div>
    <button type="button" onclick='document.getElementById("header").innerHTML = "yea"'>Click Me!</button>
</body>
</html>
```

**Note: I had to replace your image since it's a local file.**

Comment: Excellent help! I made a few changes as you suggested and it absolutely worked! Thanks!

Comment: @MisterTams no problem. That's what the site's here for. If you're feeling good about it, throw it an upvote or click that semi-transparent check mark next to the answer and accept it as gospel. Happy Coding, mate

Answer (score 0):

I have an alternative if your heart isn't set on JavaScript. Animate.css is an incredible stylesheet that will do the same thing in a much easier fashion. (Plus it's pure CSS so much better and more uniform support)

Import this in the head

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.7.0/animate.min.css" />
```

Then here is your according code:

```
   <div style="position: relative; left: 0; top: 0;">
    <img src="gibson1.png" id="guitar1"  width="500" />
    <img src="gibson2.png" id="guitar2" class="animated fadeOut delay-5s" style="animation-duration: 3s;" width="500" />
</div>
```

May not be quite the answer you're looking for but it is so much easier to do then JS + JQ animations. 

 All the best!

Comment: Looks very cool and I will try this out as well! But I guess my heart is set on JavaScript for this particular problem. Great input!