# Fade out a new row in CSS

Tags: css, row, fadeout

So I have this table, where I know how to highlight the 2nd child. However I want it to fade out, such that it is evident that a new row is added. At the moment, the 2nd row is always highlighted, however would like some guidance in how to to fade out for CSS(not havent used jquery in my code)

I have noticed there is fadeout option in jquery, but can someone tell me how to fadeout in plain css. Below is the line that highlights the 2nd row. i would like to fade out to denote that a new row was added to the table.

```
tr:nth-child(2){background-color: red;}
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understood what you asked, you can do it with `animation`

```
tr:nth-child(2){
  background-color: red;
  animation: fadeout 2s forwards;
}

@keyframes fadeout {
    to {
        background-color:#ffffff;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This does work, however everytime I reload the page this animation kicks in. I want the animation to kick in ONLY if a new row is added. Not everytime I refresh the page.

Comment: If you don't tell us how do you get this new row, we can't give you a precise answer. Post the code where we can see how you get the new row.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider `CSS` [:target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target).

> The :target CSS pseudo-class represents a unique element (the target
>   element) with an id matching the URL's fragment.

Give each of your table rows a unique `id`. Using `:target` in our CSS, we can intercept the existence of that id **in the address bar** and trigger the fade out animation accordingly. The animation will *only* occur on page refresh if the `id` in the address bar fragment matches the `id` on the `<tr>`.

```css
@keyframes fadeRow {
  from {
    background-color: red;
  }
  to {
    background-color: transparent;
  }
}

/* 
   If the address bar fragment matches the id of the 
   <tr>, trigger the fadeRow animation for only that <tr>.
*/
tr:target {
  animation: 1s fadeRow forwards;
}

/* Generic styles */
table { width: 100%; }
td { padding: .25em .5em; }
a { display: block; margin-bottom: .5em; }
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="row_1">
      <td>one</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="row_2">
      <td>two</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<!-- Matches www.mysite.com#row_1 -->
<a href="#row_1">Simulate fadeout row 1</a>

<!-- Matches www.mysite.com#row_2 -->
<a href="#row_2">Simulate fadeout row 2</a>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/orLbwm58/

Answer (score 0):

You are searching for [transitions](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp). You can see some good examples/suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15907079/css3-transition-fade-out-effect).

My recommendation is learning to use `ease-out`.