# Apply a css-value with jQuery but check if it is specified already

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, random

I am using jQuery to apply background-images to randomly selected DIV elements.

The problem is that I want to make sure that no two DIV elements can have the same background-image at any given time. So when the code chooses a DIV to apply the background-image, it should also check if any of the DIVs are already using that image in that moment.

I have put together a piece of code with a lot of help from others while searching for a solution, but it does **not** check if any of the DIVs are already using that image in that moment. As a result it often happens that two or more DIVs have the same background-image at the same time...

Here is my code:

```js
var urls = [
     'url(https://placekitten.com/g/350/150)',
     'url(https://placekitten.com/g/300/550)',
     'url(https://placekitten.com/g/400/200)',
     'url(https://placekitten.com/g/350/750)',
     'url(https://placekitten.com/g/250/600)',
     'url(https://placekitten.com/g/400/150)',
     'url(https://placekitten.com/g/300/600)',
     'url(https://placekitten.com/g/450/350)'
   ];
   // Select the next image
   var active = Math.floor(Math.random() * (urls.length - 4)) + 1

   setInterval(function() {

  // Select randomnly the next div to change
  var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
  
  // Store this list, so that we only make one call to the page
  let images = $('.image');
  
  let datachanged = images.attr("data-changed");
  
  while(rand == datachanged)
  rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
   
  let current = $('.image:nth-child('+(rand+1)+')');
  
  current.toggleClass("show hide");
  
  // The fade effect takes 400ms
  
  setTimeout(function(){
  
    current.css('background-image', urls[active]);
    
    images[0].setAttribute("data-changed", rand);
  
    current.toggleClass("hide show");
  
  },400);
   
  // Change active value so that the background will not be same next time
  active++;
  
  active = (active == urls.length) ? 0 : active ;
  
   }, 2000);
```

```css
body { margin: 0; font-size: 0;}

.image {
  background-size: cover;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 23%;
  padding-top: 23%;
  margin: 1%;
  transition: opacity 0.4s ease;
}

.image:nth-of-type(1) { 
  background-image: url(https://placekitten.com/g/350/150); 
}
.image:nth-of-type(2) { 
  background-image: url(https://placekitten.com/g/300/550); 
}
.image:nth-of-type(3) { 
  background-image: url(https://placekitten.com/g/400/200); 
}
.image:nth-of-type(4) { 
  background-image: url(https://placekitten.com/g/350/750); 
}

.show {
      opacity: 1;
}

.hide {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="images">
  <div class="image"></div>
  <div class="image"></div>
  <div class="image"></div>
  <div class="image"></div>
</div>
```

And here is the [same code on jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sublines/bykes31d/26/).

Comment: You want to change one image at a time (when timer triggers) or there can be many swaps simultaneously?

Comment: What if you stored the rand nums in an array, each time the timeout hits, push the new value of the rand into the array and check the next value randomly generated to see if it is .inArray(), if it is in the array, do not push that value into the array. Continue with this logic until you have 4 values in your array. Check the length of the array, if it less than 4, push the new value into the array, if it is equal to 4, push the new length in and then remove the last value so you always have 4 values that do not match.

Comment: Hey @dalelandry, I'm open to whatever solution works. Just keep in mind that it should also be able to work with any number of DIVs. I have an example here with 8 DIVs: https://jsfiddle.net/sublines/bdtq5cnz/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use data to store the index of the image used. Then in each interval you can exclude the once used from the main urls array. Then choose a random index to store in element data.

Also, I changed the class toggle to jQuery `.fadeIn()` and `.fadeOut()` as the provide more stable approach with callbacks.

Make sure that the array of the images urls is more than the divs that you have.

```js
let urls = [
  'https://source.unsplash.com/5E5N49RWtbA/300x300',
  'https://source.unsplash.com/G85VuTpw6jg/300x300',
  'https://source.unsplash.com/fIq0tET6llw/300x300',
  'https://source.unsplash.com/P_0R02ArdLE/300x300',
  'https://source.unsplash.com/PC_lbSSxCZE/300x300',
  'https://source.unsplash.com/nptLmg6jqDo/300x300',
  'https://source.unsplash.com/1_CMoFsPfso/300x300',
  'https://source.unsplash.com/mk7D-4UCfmg/300x300'
];

// Get reference to divs and assign images on inital load
let images = $('.image');
let unusedDivs;

images.each(function(i, e) {
  jQuery(this).css('background-image', `url(${urls[i]})`);
  jQuery(this).data("image-index", i).data("div-used", false);
});

let lastImageIndex = null;

setInterval(function() {
  // Get indexes that are already in ue
  const usedIdx = images.map(function(i, e) {
    return jQuery(e).data("image-index");
  }).get();

  // Filter indexes of urls that are not displayed yet
  const unusedIdx = [];
  urls.forEach(function(url, i) {
    if (usedIdx.indexOf(i) == -1)
      unusedIdx.push(i);
  });

  // get images div that not in use yet
  unusedDivs = jQuery('.image').filter(function(i, e) {
    return $(e).data("div-used") == false;
  });

  // Choose a random index from the unused indexes array
  const randUnsedIdx = Math.floor(Math.random() * unusedIdx.length);

  // Chose a random image div to apply image to
  const randDivIdx = Math.floor(Math.random() * unusedDivs.length);
  const current = unusedDivs.eq(randDivIdx);
  lastImageIndex = randDivIdx;

  // Get index number
  const imgUrlIdx = unusedIdx[randUnsedIdx];

  // fade out old image then on callback set the url of the new image
  // then fade it in and assign the index to the dive so in next 
  // iteration we can filter it out
  current.fadeOut(400, function() {
    current.css('background-image', `url(${urls[imgUrlIdx]})`);
    current.fadeIn();
    current.data("image-index", imgUrlIdx).data("div-used", true);
    
    // if all unsed divs have been used then reset
    if (unusedDivs.length == 1)
      jQuery('.image').data("div-used", false);

  });

}, 2000);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 0;
}

.image {
  background-size: cover;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 23%;
  padding-top: 23%;
  margin: 1%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="images">
  <div class="image"></div>
  <div class="image"></div>
  <div class="image"></div>
  <div class="image"></div>
  <div class="image"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the well-documented code! Using Unsplash is also very clever as it helps to see if an image is already used or not. I've tried your code in jsFiddle and it works pretty well except that it sometimes chooses a DIV that was just chosen the last time. I don't want it to choose the same DIV twice in a row but I guess I should have made that clear in my question. Here is your code on jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sublines/5ghcv3yu/5/ 
Could you update it to solve the last issue?

Comment: No problem. I updated my answer. I added a "div-used" data that decrease every interval then gets reset when it’s all used. This way all image divs will be used before starting over.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of saving the 'last active img index' as a data attribute, I just created a `selectedImages` which holds the state of images displayed in divs: initial is [1,2,3,4]

And when looking for next unique random, I just do in a do while look, until I get the value that is not in `selectedImages`:

```
do{
      active = Math.floor(Math.random() * (urls.length - 2)) + 1
    } while(selectedImages.indexOf(active) != -1)
```

Here is the full snippet

```js
var urls = [
         'url(https://placekitten.com/g/350/150)',
         'url(https://placekitten.com/g/300/550)',
         'url(https://placekitten.com/g/400/200)',
         'url(https://placekitten.com/g/350/750)',
         'url(https://placekitten.com/g/250/600)',
         'url(https://placekitten.com/g/400/150)',
         'url(https://placekitten.com/g/300/600)',
         'url(https://placekitten.com/g/450/350)'
       ];
       // Select the next image
        var selectedImages = [1,2,3,4] // initial state of divs img urls
        var lastSelectedDiv = -1; // initial state of last selected div

       setInterval(function() {
       var active; 
        do{
          active = Math.floor(Math.random() * (urls.length - 2)) + 1
        } while(selectedImages.indexOf(active) != -1) // get a unique image (not in current ones that are displayed)
      // Select randomnly the next div to change which is diffrent than the lastSelectedDiv
        var rand;
        do{
        rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4); // get a random value until its not the same as lastSelectedDiv
        } while(rand == lastSelectedDiv)
        selectedImages[rand] = active;

        lastSelectedDiv = rand; // override lastSelectedDiv to new random value so that next time it must be different
      let current = $('.image:nth-child('+(rand+1)+')');
      
      current.toggleClass("show hide");
      
      // The fade effect takes 400ms
      
      setTimeout(function(){
      
        current.css('background-image', urls[active]);
      
      
        current.toggleClass("hide show");
      
      },400);

      
       }, 2000);
```

```css
body { margin: 0; font-size: 0;}

    .image {
      background-size: cover;
      display: inline-block;
      width: 23%;
      padding-top: 23%;
      margin: 1%;
      transition: opacity 0.4s ease;
    }

    .image:nth-of-type(1) { 
      background-image: url(https://placekitten.com/g/350/150); 
    }
    .image:nth-of-type(2) { 
      background-image: url(https://placekitten.com/g/300/550); 
    }
    .image:nth-of-type(3) { 
      background-image: url(https://placekitten.com/g/400/200); 
    }
    .image:nth-of-type(4) { 
      background-image: url(https://placekitten.com/g/350/750); 
    }

    .show {
          opacity: 1;
    }

    .hide {
      opacity: 0;
    }
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div id="images">
      <div class="image"></div>
      <div class="image"></div>
      <div class="image"></div>
      <div class="image"></div>
    </div>
```

Edit here is a fiddle for 8 divs: https://jsfiddle.net/pascrzx9/1/ - I marked each div img with a different number, so we dont relay on colors only (sometimes I thought Im colorblind or its a bugged code :P)

Comment: So if I have more than four DIVs, I just change this line, right?: 
`var selectedImages = [1,2,3,4]`

Comment: I've tried this with 9 DIVs and I've changed that line to: `var selectedImages = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]` but for some reason it sometimes selects an image that is already used by one of the other DIVs in that moment..

Comment: If you have 9 divs, and only 8 images, its not possible to have all divs with unique images :P

Comment: but yes, you will have to change that `var selectedImages = [1,2,3,4]`, in order to support more than 4 elements

Comment: I have 8 DIVs and 11 images and I have also changed that line of code but it still chooses images that are already used: https://jsfiddle.net/sublines/bdtq5cnz/2/ 

Also, it sometimes chooses a DIV that was just chosen the last time. I don't want it to choose the same DIV twice in a row but I guess I should have made that clear in my question..

Comment: true, if that was te case, you will have to store `lastSelectedDiv` and then get the `var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);` in a `do{ ..} while(rand != lastSelectedDiv)`

Comment: Sounds good but I don't understand it. Would you be so kind and update your answer to include a solution for BOTH issues (not selecting an image that is already used + not selecting a DIV twice in a row)? I would then be able to mark it as solved and be happy to give you the bounty.

Comment: I adjusted the code to your need, also I added some comments so you can analyze the code yourself ;p

Comment: Thanks for updating your code. I've pasted it into this fiddle but the problem still persists. It still often chooses an image that is already used by another DIV in that moment: https://jsfiddle.net/sublines/bdtq5cnz/6/

Comment: There was a small mistake in your code, I adjusted it and prepare another fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/25jebsmz/1/ - also each image has its own different size, so we dont relay on the color only (they are sometimes confusing to spot the difference)

Comment: Hi, thanks for checking and updating the code. There seems to be a bug in your fiddle though. When I run the code, it now always chooses the exact same image every time..

Comment: Woops, wrong fiddle pasted :P my bad here is the correct one: https://jsfiddle.net/pascrzx9/1/