# How to fade out images on click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I recently got into coding and I'm enjoying it pretty much. With that being said, I'm pretty new to it and very... rookie. I was wondering if there's a way I can make my centered Icon fade out instead of just disappearing on click. The same goes for the overlay that I've created.

```js
function functionHide(divId, divId2, ) {
  let x = document.getElementById(divId);
  let y = document.getElementById(divId2);
  x.style.display = "none";
  y.style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
#icon {
  content: url('https://i.picsum.photos/id/178/536/354.jpg?hmac=ehK1NKjWRA3SRY3R4dCo7ejDyrzqqjDWwtwo2TYLpHk');
  height: 256px;
  width: 256px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  position: fixed;
  margin-top: -128px;
  margin-left: -128px;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: .4s ease;
  display: block;
}

#overlay {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
}

#icon:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: scale(1.5);
  transition: transform .4s;
}
```

```html
<div id="icon" onclick="functionHide('icon', 'overlay')"></div>
<div id="background">
  <div id="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Might want to try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15907079/css3-transition-fade-out-effect

Comment: e a look to https://github.com/nefe/You-Dont-Need-jQuery#8.3

Answer (score 0):

Use a `@keyframes` animation or change the opacity of the image, granted that the `transition` was set.

### `@keyframes`

```js
function functionHide(divId, divId2, ) {
  let x = document.getElementById(divId);
  let y = document.getElementById(divId2);
  x.style.animation = "fadeOut 0.2s forwards";
  y.style.animation = "fadeOut 0.2s forwards";
}
```

```css
#icon {
  content: url('https://i.picsum.photos/id/178/536/354.jpg?hmac=ehK1NKjWRA3SRY3R4dCo7ejDyrzqqjDWwtwo2TYLpHk');
  height: 256px;
  width: 256px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  position: fixed;
  margin-top: -128px;
  margin-left: -128px;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: .4s ease;
  display: block;
}

#overlay {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
}

#icon:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: scale(1.5);
  transition: transform .4s;
}
@keyframes fadeOut{
  from{
    opacity:1;
  }
  to{
    opacity:0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="icon" onclick="functionHide('icon', 'overlay')"></div>
<div id="background">
  <div id="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

Explanation

```
fadeOut 0.2s forwards
^       ^    ^
name of animation
        duration of animation
             instructs the animation to run once, then stay in the same state after animation
```

Or you can consider using the jQuery `fadeOut()` function like so:

```js
function functionHide(divId, divId2, ) {
  let x = document.getElementById(divId);
  let y = document.getElementById(divId2);
  $(x).fadeOut();
  $(y).fadeOut();
}
```

```css
#icon {
  content: url('https://i.picsum.photos/id/178/536/354.jpg?hmac=ehK1NKjWRA3SRY3R4dCo7ejDyrzqqjDWwtwo2TYLpHk');
  height: 256px;
  width: 256px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  position: fixed;
  margin-top: -128px;
  margin-left: -128px;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: .4s ease;
  display: block;
}

#overlay {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
}

#icon:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: scale(1.5);
  transition: transform .4s;
}
@keyframes fadeOut{
  from{
    opacity:1;
  }
  to{
    opacity:0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="icon" onclick="functionHide('icon', 'overlay')"></div>
<div id="background">
  <div id="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a good fade in [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11679567/using-css-for-a-fade-in-effect-on-page-load/11681331#11681331).

Use an animation in the hide class, for example:

```
.hide {
    animation-name: fadeOut;
    animation-duration: 3s;
}

@keyframes fadeOut {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

Remember to use browser extensions like `-webkit` or `-moz`.